# Delphi : in CreateForm, how to tell which component creation is slow

Tags: delphi

In my program, the creation of the main form is slow : I have identified that it hangs for around two seconds just before the form's `OnCreate` event is called. So I suspect this is happening while the components are created.

Since this form has several frames, I wonder if there is a way to "profile" component creation in order to see where I can improve. I suspect the lag comes from the opening of a database table that should not be open at that time (rather later, after some filtering is in place).

If there is a way get an event triggered before/after each component creation, I could do the profiling myself (with codesite for example).

Or maybe it is possible to do the component creation manually ?

Comment: "I suspect the lag comes from the opening of a table" Do you mean a DB table?

Comment: @kobik yes a DB Table

Comment: So surely you need to profile your db connection and datasets/queries open operations. before/after  component creation wont give you the indication  you are looking for.

Comment: @kobik It will tell me if I'm searching in the right direction since no dataset/query should be open at component creation time. If it's a DB problem, I should get interesting information (table name). And if it's not I will not waste time looking in the wrong place.

Comment: use something like Delphi Detours or Jedi CodeLib to override virtual procedure `TObject.AfterConstruction` to log (if some global flag is enabled) the object classname and, if available, name. Override the form's `AfterConstruction` to enable logging - before calling `inherited;` - and to re-disable logging after it.

Comment: If you're concerned about an open dataset/query: search your dfm's for `Active = True`. By far the easiest way to check your concern.

Comment: I currently have the same issue. Form loading is slow in the IDE *and* runtime.  With *Use debug DCUs* on I can trace this into System.Classes, where after recursively reading the stream the cleanup code TReader.DoFixupReferences takes 3 minutes on aPropFixup.ResolveReference(Reference) for a DevEx component. No IDE activity found with ProcMon. No more info at this stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty way to work out where the delay is:

- Take a copy of the `Classes` unit source code and place it in your project's source folder. This will ensure that this unit is compiled into your program rather than the one supplied with Delphi.
- Modify the code in the constructor of `TComponent`. All streamed components pass through here during creation. Add code to log the class name, e.g. using CodeSite for instance.
- Run your program, and then inspect the resulting log to identify the delay.

If you have many components then just knowing the class might not narrow it down. You might inject logging code into `TComponent.SetName` instead which will let you log the component's name. However, the basic idea is simple enough, and you should be able to apply it to your setting in order to find out the information you need.

Comment: The same can't be accomplished by creating a hack class?

Comment: @JerryDodge Don't know what a "hack class" is.

Comment: `type TComponent = class(System.Classes.TComponent) ... end;` at the top of the unit... but I answered my own question - that would have to be defined everywhere that a `TComponent` is found. Easier to do as you say and make a copy.

Comment: That is known as an interposer. And you'd need to interpose every class type in the dfm file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Since I am using Delphi 10 Seattle, I copied the `System.Classes.pas` file. When I add `CodeSiteLogging` as the first unit in the Interface uses list, I get "Insufficient memory" at compile time. Should I put it somewhere else or just discard CodeSite for this stuff because hacking into `TComponent` is too low level for CodeSite ?

Comment: You can't modify interface section. Only implementation. CodeSite is a sledgehammer mind you, although it will work. I'd just throw in a call to AllocConsole and start calling WriteLn.

Comment: that really is dirty and would not work with BPLs ! why not just edit VMT  and hijack TObject.AfterConstruction without doing anything hackerish?

Comment: It's not meant to be elegant. Just to work whilst debugging.

Comment: `TReader` has events that are fired when component classes are being searched and created during DFM streaming. You could bypass the Form's native DFM streaming and then use a manual `TReader` object wiith event handlers assigned to it for logging, and then manually invoke DFM streaming using that reader.

Comment: I ended up creating a log file (AllocConsole would only scroll a few hundred lines) but hacking Tcomponent.create didn't help. I see the 2 seconds lag but I don't really know what is going on at that time. Remy's suggestion looks more promising.

Comment: That won't give you any more information. You've been able to identify which control takes time to startup. Now you can dig deeper. Remy is just offering an alternative approach to get the same info, less hacky, but perhaps a bit more involved to set up.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not sure : this is what I got :
    12:14:54.942 : TcxFreeNotificator
    12:14:56.975 : TcxGridTopDetailsSiteViewInfo
(two DevExpress components). I don't know what the first one does, I see it hundreds of times not inducing lag. I thought Remy's approach would be more on the Form's side rather than from inside the component (but maybe you are right and I'll get the same information)